# Nodejs make automatic csrf protection

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, csrf, csrf-protection

Well i am building simple nodejs cms. My question is simple how can i make automatic CSRF protection? Because i think its dangerous and i can miss this protection in form or route. Is there any way how to automatize this proccess?

At this moment i am using this.

Routes.js

```
// CSRF
var csrfProtection = csrf({
    cookie: true
})
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
})

// Register
router.get("/register", csrfProtection, shouldNotBeAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.render("../modules/users/views/register", {
        title: 'Register',
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken
    });
});

router.post("/register", parseForm, csrfProtection, authController.user_reigster);
```

Form

```
<form method="post" action="/users/register">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
```

package CSURF.

Thank for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are on the right track.

The middleware should be applied to ALL POST requests*.  An example on the CSURF readme shows the way to do it (worth reading carefully):

```
// mount api before csrf is appended to the app stack
app.use('/api', api)

// now add csrf and other middlewares, after the "/api" was mounted
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))
```

You should be using a templating language for the user interface.  You should have either a template for forms or a filter that looks for forms which include the CSRF attributes in the form when rendering.

If you are making AJAX POSTs ([XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)), that will also need to be thought through and is well covered on this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628343/express-js-csrf-token-with-jquery-ajax).

* if you have api routes, the should be grouped and excluded from CSRF.

Comment: Thanks successfully implemented :D yes sometimes is good to read documentation ...