# Rest-auth still reports the error of "CSRF cookie not set", but I've set the csrf

Tags: node.js, django, rest, cookies

I tried to implement an authentication(login/registration) function using Django rest-auth package.

```
url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
```

But when I tried to post the rest-auth urls, it gave me the error:
[image: screenshot from chrome console]

However, in Nodejs I've already set the csrf token using the 'csurf' package,

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const csrf = require('csurf');
const app = new Express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));
```

Also, I can see the csrf token using Fiddler:
[image: screenshot from fiddler]

Could you help me figure out where is the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token in your request is currently named `_csrf`. It needs to be called `csrfmiddlewaretoken` for Django to pick it up.

Comment: Very appreciate your suggestion. I think that's the correct direction. I add the csrfmiddlewaretoken and it works partially.

Comment: Partially? How so?

Comment: I am putting details on this post. I wrote my code according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060044/express-csrf-token-validation

Comment: If I've fixed the `CSRF cookie not set` error, accept my answer and ask another question.

Comment: I created a new post here, welcome to answer me if you have time. Thanks.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101642/nodejs-how-to-set-csrf-token-correctly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Raphael Gomes. I made some progress on this.
I changed my server.js file as:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const csrf = require('csurf');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('csrfmiddlewaretoken', req.csrfToken());
  next();
});
```

And in the Fiddler,
[image]

I can see 2 csrfs there, one default and one set by me. I tried to remove app.use(csrf({ cookie: true })); but then it shows csrf misconfigued. Anyway, at least csrfmiddlewaretoken works in this way.

Then the authentication result is like:
[image]

[image]

It says this csrf token is not valid. I think that's because I used the req.csrfToken(). I am still researching that how to set the correct csrf token.