# NodeJS how to set csrf token correctly?

Tags: node.js, django, authentication, cookies, csrf

This is a continuation of this question: [Rest-auth still reports the error of "CSRF cookie not set", but I've set the csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099083/rest-auth-still-reports-the-error-of-csrf-cookie-not-set-but-ive-set-the-csr)

```
The code I used for server.js is:
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const csrf = require('csurf');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('csrfmiddlewaretoken', req.csrfToken());
  next();
});
```

However, the result is 
[image]

[image]

The reason I think is that I didn't set the cookie correctly. I tried to remove app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));, but then it shows an error of *csrf misconfigured.*
[image]

In fiddler, I can see there are two tokens in the cookie, one default, one set by *res.cookie('csrfmiddlewaretoken', req.csrfToken());*, how can I set the cookie in the correct way?

**UPDATE:**

I kind of figured out a brute-force way to change the name of _csrf to csrfmiddlewaretoken.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('csrfmiddlewaretoken', req.cookies._csrf);
  next();
})
```

Then, in fiddler, I see the value are same.

[image]

But the django rest-auth still reports fail like:
[image]

Maybe that's not about the name. I am still researching....

Comment: What does this has to do with django-rest-framework ?

Comment: I used django rest-auth package here, logging in and registration use POST to url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')). And the error information is from there. You can look at my former question,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099083/rest-auth-still-reports-the-error-of-csrf-cookie-not-set-but-ive-set-the-csr. Someone helped me figure out that only csrfmiddlewaretoken can be picked up by django, not _csrf.

Comment: My current problem is there are 2 csrf tokens in my cookie (as the screeshot above), _csrf and csrfmiddlewaretoken. The value csrfmiddlewaretoken is incorrect so the authentication fails. I think the value of _csrf is correct but the name is inproper. It should be changed to csrfmiddlewaretoken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JiPanNYC, maybe you forgot to add

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

in your settings.py