# Submit form in Ajax without JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to follow [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) guide to update a form field when the user change another field.

I've correctly setup my FormTypes, but I'm having trouble submitting the form in Ajax **without JQuery**.

I have 2 select :

```
const blockchain = document.getElementById('strategy_farming_blockchain');
const dapp = document.getElementById('strategy_farming_dapp');
const csrf = document.getElementById('strategy_farming__token');
```

The `blockchain` field is supposed to update the `dapp` field.

If I submit the whole form, it's working :

```
blockchain.addEventListener('change', function () {
    const form = this.closest('form');
    const method = form.method;
    const url = form.action;

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    request.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            //Success
            const html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.response, 'text/html');
            dapp.innerHTML = html.querySelector('#strategy_farming_dapp').innerHTML;
        } else {
            //Error from server
            console.log('Server error');
        }
    };

    request.onerror = function () {
        //Connection error
        console.log('Connection error');
    };

    request.send(new FormData(form));
});
```

But I'm not supposed to submit the whole form, I'm supposed to submit only the `blockchain` value

I tried a lot of things, like

```
var formdata = new FormData(form);
formdata.delete(dapp.name);
request.send(formdata);
// It's working for a new entity, but if I'm editing one, it's not updating the dapp field...
```

or

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append(this.name, this.value);
formdata.append(csrf.name, csrf.value);
request.send(formdata);
// It's working in a NEW action, but not in an EDIT action...
```

or

```
var data = {};
data[this.name] = this.value;
request.send(data);
//or
request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
//If I dump($request->request) in the controller, it seems like there's no data... 
//Or the request isn't parsed correctly, or there's something missing ?
```

I also tried with `encodeURIComponent`...

I'm out of ideas... Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892601/invalid-csrf-token-when-using-ajax) regarding the CSRF token.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I fixed the error 'The CSRF token is invalid.' it's working if I'm in a NEW action, but if it's a EDIT action it's not updating the dapp field (I check the response and there's not the new options for the dapp field...). I'll edit the post but it's not closed...

Comment: If you only send the `blockchain` erlement, how is it supposed to know what the action should be?

Comment: I also tried to send the whole form and remove only the dapp field with `formdata.delete(dapp.name);` and it's the same

Comment: I have no idea what `dapp` or why you need to remove it.

Comment: I need to update the `dapp` based on the `blockchain` field. If I change the `blockchain` field, I need to reset the `dapp` field. Are you familiar with Symfony ?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with Symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I chose to use `FormData` and remove the `dapp` field.

```
const blockchain = document.getElementById('strategy_farming_blockchain');
const dapp = document.getElementById('strategy_farming_dapp');

blockchain.addEventListener('change', function () {
    const form = this.closest('form');
    const method = form.method;
    const url = form.action;

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.withCredentials = true;
    request.open(method, url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    request.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            //Success
            const html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.response, 'text/html');
            dapp.innerHTML = html.querySelector('#strategy_farming_dapp').innerHTML;
        } else {
            //Error from server
            console.log('Server error');
        }
    };

    request.onerror = function () {
        //Connection error
        console.log('Connection error');
    };
    var formdata = new FormData(form);
    formdata.set(dapp.name, "");
    request.send(formdata);
});
```

Here's the FormType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        //...
        ->add('blockchain', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'class' => Blockchain::class,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-select2'],
        ]);

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Blockchain $blockchain = null) {
        $dapps = null === $blockchain ? [] : $blockchain->getDapps();
        $form->add('dapp', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Dapp::class,
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => $dapps,
            'placeholder' => 'My placeholder',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-select2'],
        ]);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            /**
             * @var StrategyFarming $data
             */
            $data = $event->getData();
            $blockchain = $data->getDapp() ? $data->getDapp()->getBlockchain() : null;
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $blockchain);
        }
    );

    $builder->get('blockchain')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $blockchain = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $blockchain);
        }
    );

}
```

In order for this to work, I had to add the blockchain field to my Form's Entity, so that the Request handle the field :

```
/**
 * Not persisted
 * @var Blockchain
 */
private $blockchain;

public function getBlockchain(): ?Blockchain
{
    if ($this->blockchain === null && $this->dapp !== null && $this->dapp->getBlockchain() !== $this->blockchain) {
        $this->blockchain = $this->dapp->getBlockchain();
    }
    return $this->blockchain;
}

public function setBlockchain(?Blockchain $blockchain): self
{
    $this->blockchain = $blockchain;

    return $this;
}
```